# Creating a new collection in strapi CMS

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, strapi

I know we can create entries in certain collections using the REST API but can we also create an entirely new collection from let's say front end like react using some kind of API? What my use case is that I want to create a certain entry in a collection. If that collection doesn't exist I want that collection to be created first and then I want the new entry to be created in that collection.

Comment: are you sure you want to do that? as its not how things work, you need a table/collection you can't create then at run time

Comment: Yes, I agree with mainak,  And it kind of defeats the purpose of using a headless CMS like Strapi and the convenience that comes with it. 

Also, there is a high risk of breaking the application in production.  Why if some one accidentally deletes or updates in the way that they did not expect.

Comment: ok thank you for the guidance @mainak